With CiviCRM and Drupal, how can members view their own past contributions?
I'm migrating a site from Drupal 7 and Ubercart into Drupal 10 with CiviCRM (with CiviCRM Entity). The integration is great so far.
In Ubercart, members had an Orders tab on their profile where they could view their past invoices. Now, I'd like to let members see their CiviCRM invoices.
I know I have at least two options:

build a Drupal view pulling contribution/invoice information from CiviCRM

let members view their own records within CiviCRM itself


I've made a quick attempt at both options and gotten a little stuck.
Which approach do most site builders take - direct people to their own CiviCRM contact/history page, or create Drupal views of CiviCRM data?
If you direct people to their own CiviCRM page, what permissions are needed? I've tried using Drupal permissions to give these permissions to authenticated users:

CiviCRM: view my invoices
CiviContribute: access CiviContribute
CiviContribute: make online contributions

but when I try to go to a member's individual CiviCRM page, I get access denied, even when I'm already logged in as a member.
I'd like an individual member to be able to view all their own contribution and payment info, but not any CiviCRM info for any other member.
If, instead, I build a Drupal View, what content type do I choose, and what relationships do I need to set up to be able to show a table of the member's past donations and membership payments?
Thank you very much!

When you say "go to a member's individual CiviCRM page" do you mean their contact record? There's another page, found at civicrm/user, which just requires minimal permissions and has a listing of their stuff. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#giving-users-the-ability-to-view-their-contact-dashboard
You can see it in the sandbox at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/user
If you have tax+invoicing enabled under civicontribute component settings, then it also allows downloading invoices.

Yes, that's what I mean - and civicrm/user might be exactly what I need! Thank you - I didn't know about that.

Ugh, sorry - hit Add Comment too soon. ...  Thanks to your helpful link, I was able to see that I needed to give Dashboard permission within Drupal - and now accessing that page works great! Unfortunately, the member's membership doesn't appear on that page - I can see it as an admin on the Contact page, but on the dashboard, no memberships appear in that section. Any idea what I should check? Thank you!

I'm not sure. The memberships section seems pretty simple: It just loads active and inactive ones for the user. It doesn't show test memberships, if that's the problem.

Hm. I wonder if the problem is that it's an imported membership. I'll do some more testing with new memberships created in CiviCRM and see if that at least behaves differently. Interestingly, I have a User view block on the Drupal profile page that pulls CiviCRM Membership Type and Expiration, and that works just fine, so they seem to have enough permissions to see the data in some circumstances. I'll do some more testing and report back. Thank you so much for your quick and helpful reply!

way back in the Stone Age: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=12261.0.html - no idea if that is still the issue, but i stumbled across it y'day when look for a reason why we were not seeing 'renew' option in the Dashboard

I think something must be wrong with Search Kit. When I try viewing the User Dashboard, I get errors - .....   Referrer
Message  $API Request Authorization failed =
#0 /home/sitename/myslte/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(151): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("API Request Authorization failed", TRUE)
#1 /home/sitename/myslte/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(256): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOGetAction))
.....  is there a way to reinstall Search Kit, or something else I can try? Thank you!
